# jQuery accordion is not working uploaded at server

Tags: jquery, accordion

I did a part of a website using mainly html and css and inserting some js an query scripts (my first time with js and jQuery). It worked properly on my computer and uploaded to DropBox too (proved in several computers).

But a jQuery accordion is not working now that my client uploaded the website in her server.The accordion is not opening. I don't know what to do.

here you can check the section of the website which the accordion working in DropBox:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100800235/EMC-%20web%20caleidoscopio%202/temas.html

and here you can download the files I gave to my client:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100800235/EMC-%20web%20caleidoscopio%202.zip

Any clue or tips will be more than welcome.

Comment: Has jquery been loaded in the correct part? Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: It work at dropbox (I supposed it is loaded in the correct part. I did not uploaded to the sever, my client did, but she tried several times, downloading and loading it again. I'm not sure if I'm answering what you are asking..

Comment: The link you gave isnt a clients server, its dropbox so where is the code live, as that's the issue? I don't know where the accordion should be on the site you linked but i clicked the titles and nothing happened. You need to open developer tools in firefox or chrome, go to the website and inspect the console for jquery errors

Comment: For example, trying to load your site on dropbox returns this error in the console: 'Blocked loading mixed active content "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"'

Comment: My client (the person who hired me) uploaded it, but as long as it's not working, she removed it. Tthere are two links: one is the section where the accordion is (action: temas: when you click for instance "himno a la alegría", the accordion opens and show the content. Is not working on your computer? Nothing on my console of errors..

Comment: Aisss....sorry, I'm a newbie. the problem could be that somewhere on the code is the "jquery.min.js" file wrong directed? that's what your comment mean?

Comment: What i mean is where it is hosted on the dropbox servers, jQuery is being blocked so i cannot see anything working as the code is being blocked from being shown. You need to upload it to a proper server so we can see what is happening. It is impossible to debug it when dropbox servers are blocking key codes from loading

Comment: It will be working locally for you, but the dropbox servers are blocking external codes. Either strip out the code and put it on jsfiddle to make a working example or upload what you have to a proper host and we can look at it there

Comment: thank you very much for your patience, andy! here you have it uploaded where it is supposed to be. this is the the link to the section where the accordion is,  when you click on the list (for instance "Himno a la alegria") it does not open. http://www.musicacreativa.com/wp-content/uploads/discos/caleidoscopio/temas.html

Comment: If you go to that page, open developer tools in firefox/chrome by hitting F12, and look on the console, you'll see a whole array of internal error 500 messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Internal 500 Errors]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7C0a.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7C0a.jpg)

Here is a screenshot of the errors in the console. This will be why nothing is working

Comment: 500 internal server error is the 99% of the errors, So, basically is an error of the server? nothing to do with the website?

Comment: It's either the file doesn't exist or it's being linked to wrong or something. I'd check everything is where it should be and that your server handles php/mysql etc okay

Comment: thank you very much!! I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: now that I know a little more with your help, I've opened a new question more specific. :)